# android development open file txt and return content

Tags: java, android, file-io

Search all over the internet and could not find a working code.
How can i get content of a txt document and return it.

Suppose i have a txt file in ( src/my.proovi.namespace/data.txt )
And i created a method called refresh_all_data(); where i want the data to be collected and returned.
In the main activity method i just need to get the content as ( String content = refresh_all_data(); ) And thats it.

Should be easy but just cant find a working answer.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Mybe i am just a beginner and thats why just could get it to work. I deleted all and posted this message So cant provide what i have treid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the file in the `/assets` folder of your project, then you can get an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) by opening it throught the `AssetManager`:

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("data.txt");
```

You can then read lines from the file and add them to a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) by using a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html):

```
//The buffered reader has a method readLine() that reads an entire line from the file, InputStreamReader is a reader that reads from a stream.
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
//This is the StringBuilder that we will add the lines to:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
String line;
//While we can read a line, append it to the StringBuilder:
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
}
//Close the stream:
reader.close();
//and return the result:
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: getAssets cannot be resolved . 
The method readLine() is undefined for the type Reader

Comment: @RasimMehtijev, sorry, typo on my part, reader should be of type `BufferedReader` instead of just `Reader`, and I missed the parentheses after `getAssets()`.

Comment: Unhandled exception type IOException. shows on getAssets().open("data.txt");
 This is the part where i get realy confused Eclipse suggest to surraund it with try/catch. This is where all goes whrong.

Comment: Read up a bit on [exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). For a simple case like this, it should be enough if you surround the contents of the method with `try{//all code from the method goes here}catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); return ""; }`

Comment: Thank you very much Got it to work. Will add a complited code.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below code in one function and call it wherever you want.

```
try{
      // Open the file that is the first 
      // command line parameter
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
      // Get the object of DataInputStream
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
      //Read File Line By Line
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      // Print the content on the console
      System.out.println (strLine);
      }
      //Close the input stream
      in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
```

Comment: here strLine will have all the content of the file. so in the method you can returns that string

Comment: Please give the reason for the down vote. and what am i missing here. so i can improve that

Comment: Sorry i just could get it to work. I have tried this peace of code many times. I Think i just need more practise and knowledge to get it to work But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what i got.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String test = null;
    try {
        test = refresh_all_data();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TextView day1Label = new TextView(this);  
    day1Label.setText(test);
    setContentView(day1Label);

}
```

And the refresh_all_data(); method.

```
private String refresh_all_data() throws IOException
{ 

    InputStream in = getAssets().open("data.txt");
    //The buffered reader has a method readLine() that reads an entire line from the file, InputStreamReader is a reader that reads from a stream.
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    //This is the StringBuilder that we will add the lines to:
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
    String line;
    //While we can read a line, append it to the StringBuilder:
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        sb.append(line);
    }
    //Close the stream:
    reader.close();
    //and return the result:
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thanks allot to Jave.