# List view should show a text view after click on list item

Tags: android, list, listview, textview

as a beginner I am trying do develope a simple bedtime story app (about 10 to 30 stories for the first on Android.

The idea was to have a listview where each list item shows the title of the story. - I have no idea how to add dynamically a specific title (think the best way would be from the headline of the .txt file), so each list item becomes the name "story" + i (i for the counted list item).

In the next step - if an item (story) is clicked - the app should just show a simple textview were full story (about 200 words) can be read.

As you see the idea i got from the web to get the story texts is to write the stories in a .txt file, put in the assests order and then read it via fileInpitStream.

The text files are named for the first and easy like "story1.txt" "story2.txt" and so on.

***So my biggest problem is how is it possible to combine every list item with the following matching text file "-.txt" when a list item gets clicked?***

If you need any further information (XML files - but mostly standard - or other) please tell me. I am very thankful for every answer i get to help me to implement my little idea!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


List valueList = new ArrayList<String>();

//filling List Items
for(int i=1;i <30; i++){
    valueList.add("Story " +i);
}

//List Adapter
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
        R.layout.custom_textview, valueList);  
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int arg2, long arg3)
{
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(getPackageName(), getPackageName()+".ListViewShow");
intent.putExtra("selected", lv.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString());
startActivity(intent);
}
});

}
}
```

ListViewShow (where the combination from listview to textview should be):

```
public class ListViewShow extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.textview_show);
      AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
      InputStream inputStream = null;

          try {
              inputStream = assetManager.open("test.txt");
                  if ( inputStream != null)
                      Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }


}}
```

LogCat Error Messages:

```html
 09-27 17:37:56.797: W/dalvikvm(5622): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4163eba8)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622): Process: fm.de.geschichten, PID: 5622
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {fm.de.geschichten/fm.de.geschichten.ListViewShow}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at fm.de.geschichten.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:47)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
 09-27 17:37:56.827: E/AndroidRuntime(5622):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have already everything you described so why telling us this and posting all that code. You can retrieve 'story5.txt' from the intent extras in the second activity. The only thing you don't have is reading that file from assets. Instead you try to read as if it was on the file system.

Comment: Well i would not ask if i already know the solution.
i completely changed the "ListVIewShow" Activity. So but still how is it possible to get the text file to show, if i click on a list item? It always comes to an error which says Unfortunately the App has stopped..

Comment: Please edit question with logcat output if it crashes :)

Comment: You removed the determining from intent getExtras but ala that is ok for a test. Put it in again please. Your reading from assets code does look ok. Is file test.txt in assets? Further you should place a log statement in the catch block to. And look in the LogCat as it will tell you the errors and stacktraces. Post the loggcat.

Comment: I think you mean this line:   
    `// Following line just shows a simple line of text
    //((TextView)(findViewById(R.id.textView1))).setText("You selected "+intent.getStringExtra("selected")+ "!");`

So it worked with it but it doesn't seem to have any context to the test.txt file, it just shows a line, that is not what I wanted. But of course nothing from my test.txt file, which I want.



I added the LogCat messages.
Yes, the test.txt file is placed in the Assets order

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {fm.de.geschichten/fm.de.geschichten.ListViewShow}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

So make sure that you have added your activity `ListViewShow.java` in your manifest file along with other activities under Application tag.

Comment: Awesone thank you, the first step is done, I renamed it some time ago so there was a false name in the Manifest (the App only has these two Activities). So now I can click on the listview items. Now it opens a new Text view where are just the Words "Large Text" in. Well, think my problem is how to get the Text from my file in this box. Furthermore all 30 texts considering on a specific listview item.

Comment: Sadly, no. The text view which comes up if i click on a list item doesn't show the content of my test.txt file. Only "Large Text". It should show the content of my test.txt ("Hello World... Hello Android"). But it seems there is a call to the test.txt file missing. Thank you so far! Don't know how to do that. That was also mainly my initial question to the post.

Comment: Ohk.. did you debug that are you passing the clicked text properly or not?

Comment: There is no error occurring. But if I click the item, only my default textview see:   `setContentView(R.layout.textview_show);`    will be shown (where a string "Large Text" is in). But I want a connection to my text file, not to the layout xml file which only should give the style for the view.

Comment: do you mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206082/android-development-open-file-txt-and-return-content)?

Comment: I think i already got the lines which was on that problem in the link. I just do not know how to actually show the text from my test.txt file on my screen.

Edit: The debugger also says: "It worked" if i click an item. But the content of the text file still isn't shown.