# What folder should I store text files?

Tags: java, android

I have my classes in `/src/com.example.myapp/` and I have a text `mytext.txt` there too.

However, when I reference `static File f = new File("mytext.txt"));` it does not find it, even though the file is in the same directory as the class.

What do I need to do? What directory is it actually looking in?

Assets is read-only. I need somewhere where I can read and update the text file.

Comment: Are you sure your classes are in /src/com.example.myapp/ and not in /src/com/example/myapp/

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, Eclipse shows it with periods. I wasn't sure what to put.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android development open file txt and return content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206082/android-development-open-file-txt-and-return-content)

Comment: No it's not. How did you decide that? That one is not even using `File`...

Comment: If you want writable file, [put in in Internal memory of device](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the file with *EDIT* mode, you can [use Internal/External Storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#InternalVsExternalStorage)

Then you can read it as:

```
String filePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();  //returns current directory.
File file = new File(filePath, fileName);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));   
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {

}
return text.toString(); //the output text from file.
```

You can even write to this file :

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "ur data";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it will help you ツ

Answer (score 1):

Use an `assets` folder.

Here is an example...

[Loading array from a text file in assets folder (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781060/loading-array-from-a-text-file-in-assets-folder-android)

You create the `assets` folder in your root project folder then place your file in it. Once it's there, you access this way:

```
getAssets().open("file.txt");
```

the `getAssets` method is part of your Activity / Context. Context carriers a lot of the information about your app.

If you are not in an Activity, you can pass the `Context` to your class and use this:

```
context.getAssets().open("file.txt");
```

Comment: How do I import that?

Comment: @Kick - I edited my response. And thanks for the warning/suggestion!

Comment: I'm not working in an Activity class, but a class I made to just read and write. What should I import?

Comment: I edited my answer. Activity extends Context, so you need the Context of your app.

Comment: Oh, this is read-only. I need to update this file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562904/is-asset-folder-read-only

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`assets` directory](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html):

> assets/
>
> This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.

Comment: How do I reference it? `/appPackage/assets/mytext.txt`?

Comment: You should be able to use `getAssets().open("mytext.txt")`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206396/4088425

Comment: Reading the link see nothing about: Does `getAssets()` have to be imported?

Comment: You might need to import `android.content.res.AssetManager`. Here's the reference doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Comment: Tried `import android.content.res.AssetManager;` and `import android.content.res.AssetManager.*;`

Comment: If you're not in an activity, then you'll need to get a reference to the activity. You could pass a [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), which has the [`getAssets()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29) method, in when you call the function.

Comment: Oh, this is read-only. I need to update this file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562904/is-asset-folder-read-only

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) may work. Otherwise you could try @SweetWisher's solution.